# How could a K3 civilization be maintained when different parts of the civilization are thousands of lightyears apart?

Tags: space, space-colonization

A K3 civilization is a civilization that has access to the amount of power generated by a galaxy. Such a civilization would span 100s of galaxies. How can it exist as one entity if it takes thousands of years to travel from one side to the other, if you were going at light speed, without falling apart because of it being almost impossible to control an empire where if you want to create a new law or make an announcement people at the border would hear it thousands of years later?

Comment: What do you think the maximum time from a decision being made to that information arriving at the end of your empire is?  Is there a hard line, or is it that control gets more subtle and complex as your empire spreads?

Comment: If it's impossible to maintain, it seems like it would be impossible to form in the first place. Have you been able to explain how it would be created?

Answer (score 8):

The hard part about exploring K3 civilizations is that you have to start thinking differently.  Radically differently.  It should be no surprise that social structures that function on a an utterly insignificant little blue green planet orbiting a small unregarded yellow sun far out in the uncharted backwaters of the unfashionable end of the western spiral arm of the Milky Way Galaxy don't function so well spanning galaxies.

From your question, it looks like we are assuming faster than light travel.  You say 100s of galaxies, and thousands of years.  Our nearest galaxy is 2.5 *million* light years away, so it looks like you're assuming that travel is perhaps a thousand times faster than light.  I wont sweat the details.  It just means I will focus on your "thousands of years" quote.  If you indeed wanted to have only light-speed travel, the process is the same, only the numbers are much bigger and you have to start to consider things like the death of stars into your empire plan.

The actual amount of time is actually not the important part.  What matters is the dynamic range.  It's easy to rule a mountain of granite with thousand-year round trips.  Granite doesn't change much in a thousand years. It's much harder to rule a small patch of the Amazon.  The creatures in that plot might change on a minute-by-minute basis!

We're actually pretty familiar with having tremendous control over things when there's huge time scales.  Consider [these guys](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MdTS6-fbNH0).  Main Street is a wonderfully entertaining barbershop quartet.  Now I'll note that one of the defining characteristics of a good barbershop quartet is the "angel's voice."  This is an illusionary voice that only appears if the four singers are *perfectly* in tune.

They obviously have some astonishingly tight control over their voice.  But what does that really mean?  If we want to look at timescales, we're first going to have to identify what matters.  Here's a first step: [what the vocal chords look like](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-XGds2GAvGQ) while singing.  It's a bit freaky looking.  But what happens when we look at them at a different timescale?  If we look at [the vocal chords at a few thousand frames per second](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9kHdhbEnhoA), we get a very different image.  It looks almost uncontrolled.  You can see countless points in time where very localized physics causes the vocal chords to separate in slightly different ways.  You can see the cascades of energy rippling outwards to be damped by the muscles surrounding the vocal chords.  You can see the awkward moment where the voice breaks, switching between registers.

So how do we reconcile these two images?  The secret is that we humans are willing to let a lot of unpredictable things *just happen*, as long as we can, over time, stabilize the things we want to see.  Our vocal muscles stabilize the frequencies of the beats of the vocal chords.  Our lower brain then stabilizes the muscle tone of those vocal muscles in order to maintain a pitch.  Our upper brain then controls the stability of this muscle control to portray things like emotion in our singing.  Finally, we try to use that emotion to stabilize a feeling in someone else, in our audience.

A K3 civilization would have to think like this, but on a much grander scale.  It would need to have a soft but firm centralized rule that strives to stabilize the most important aspects of their rule of the empire on a timescale of many thousands of years.  They would rule like the captain of the Titanic.  No quick movements.  Just slow steady dependable adjustments.  They would need to stabilize individuals and ideas which seek to create stability themselves, but on a more local scale, under the rule of the galactic empires.  Those individuals and their ideas should stabilize the next generation of faster moving individuals, and so on and so forth.

If a disruption occurs (and it surely will), the local "government" forces should divide the disruptions effects into different time scales.  Anything which is on a timescale faster than a round-trip to the next level of government should be handled their way, on their turf.  Anything higher than that should be handled in a way which gives the next layer an opportunity to act.  Basically, they should take the rough edges off of the disruption, and turn it into a nice soft pitch that the next layer can hit out of the park.  The only issues that reach the centralized government should be the slow ones that you can afford to spend perhaps a hundred thousand years to debate on and react to.

Done correctly, it's almost seamless.  It looks like one solid indivisible entity, when it's really far more complex and beautiful.  [And beautiful it can be](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SBenttZUT7A).

Answer (score 3):

The huge civilization would be governed by the Governor, an artificial intelligence program.  There is not one Governor: there are many copies, distributed through the civilization.  More can be made on demand.

The Governor is not updated.  Each identical copy of the Governor governs its region by applying built-in principles and algorithms.  Thus, although there is not one law that applies to the entire civilization as an entity, the laws one finds in place to place are very similar, having arisen from the Governor's inherent principles as applied to the local situation.  This would be similar to the idea of a Constitution describing how government should take place, with local regions applying as they saw fit.  Except in this case there would not be squirrely locals bending the intent of the Constitution to serve their interests: the Governor's only interest is the stability of the civilization, and it impartially rules according to its principles.

An optimal constitution is like an optimal body plan: the shape of the cockroach and shark deviate little over the millennia. The Governors do not communicate with each other because there is no need.  They do not learn or adapt; they are not amended.  This leads to less flexibility as regards government, although the set of principles is turned into law according to local circumstances, and these implementations can themselves be flexible as circumstances warrant.  It also leads to stability and consistency across the civilization.

Comment: Sory but I don't understand your third paragraph, where you said that the Governor AI don't need communication with other Governors. Why it won't need to learn or adapt, always can something new appear in an entire universe, for example maybe humanity found another smart race, that would make a lot of new laws and modifications of existent laws, and this should be transmited to another Governors in order to be prepared when that happen there.

Comment: @Ender Look: /transmitted to other governors/ Transmission is the problem here.  They are distant.  One would not learn or adapt because then local copies would evolve and diverge.  The empire would not be homogenous.  The creators of the Governor have confidence / hubris that it represents the epitome of Government (like the shark is the epitome of the fish body plan) and so there is no need for it to change - in fact it might be dangerous to have it change.  One can find shades of this sort of thinking in some writings about the US Constitution and I do not say that in a pejorative way.

Answer (score 3):

The sheer closest I can fathom for an empire limited by the speed of light is the Qeng Ho from [*A Deepness in the Sky*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Deepness_in_the_Sky). And I swear I've writtenabout them on WB (or atleast on SE somewhere) before, but I can't find it. [A few other people have](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/search?q="Deepness+in+the+sky") with regards to a few topics.

The Qeng Ho weren't an empire as such, but a loose collection of disparate groups that all held the same ideals and goals; essentially a societal norm spread across light-centuries.

These groups would fly between known civilized worlds and trade in whatever might be of value. Sometimes it would be technology, or it might be goods, or it could be information. Occasionally they would arrive and find the planet having bombed itself back to the stone age and the Qeng Ho would aid in rebuilding a space faring society because they knew that in 100 or 200 years another Qeng Ho  ship (them or someone else) would be by again and the planet would have valuable trade once more.

The backbone of what made them functional was--effectively--a galactic radio station. Every Qeng Ho ship would broadcast an automated signal that would contain the blueprints necessary to go from radio ("are you recieving? Build this...") to intra-solar space travel. As well as things like language and the society of the Qeng Ho themselves, so that when the traders showed up, they could parley with minimal effort.

Underlying that was a private Qeng Ho encrypted channel that allowed groups to talk with each other. Not quickly, but still faster than their ships could travel. They'd use this channel to broadcast locations of new civilized worlds, premium technical advancements (the Qeng Ho kept the best stuff to themselves), and so forth. They knew that any given message may never be received, much less generate a reply that they would hear in their lifetimes (even long as they were due to relativistic time dilation and life prolonging technologies).

But I wouldn't call them a K3 civilization, necessarily... Just the closest thing to "a galaxy-sized society limited by the speed of light" that I am aware of. And I'm not 100% sure that this would truly work, but it is plausible enough for a novel.

Answer (score 2):

## It would never form in the first place

Going off of HDE226868's comment, unless there is a way it was formed under such conditions, then it is unreasonable to expect it to be maintained that way.

Given the rate of technological development and lifespan of our own species, there is no reason to expect that the expanders of a far-flung empire would still hold allegiance to a polity they left dozens or hundreds of lifetimes ago, can't communicate with, and could be thousands of years technologically an culturally divergent at this point.

Now, if you want us to assume that some different sent of conditions of lifespan and rate of technological development, perhaps the answer will change, but then that would be a different question.

Answer (score 1):

You honestly couldn't if you were restrained by light speed, but you could maintain one buy having them form a sort of state like government like in Greece, but he leader title would be mostly honorary and not be very powerful

Comment: This is essentially the right answer, but I'd love to see it expanded and explained in detail. Some comparisons with Rome, explanations of impacts of local conditions, cultural evolution, economic reasons why a single currency is a bad idea, the correlations between taxation and infrastructure spending; there's a lot to say on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you can travel faster than light, there is absolutely no reason why a planet would follow the laws of a central government.

If you rebelled, nobody is going to turn up and stop you for a thousand years which makes a central government pointless. Tax can't work when it takes several lifetimes to arrive. Same with trade. Same with communication.

Without faster than speed of light travel, government won't extend past a solar system at best and more than likely be just a single planet.

People will still get on generational ships and colonize new planets but they'll make their own laws.